# Set Cache Redis Expiration to 1 year

Tags: spring-mvc, caching, redis, cache-expiration

How to set Redis Cache expiration to 1 year?

I tried to set the `long` value on the xml configuration to : `31556952000` (1 year), but then it caught an exception that type Integer doesn't recognize the value as Integer. I tried to search at Google, and it says that Integer maximum value is up to `2147483647`, which means, if I set to that maximum value, I only get my cache expires on 24 days.

Here is my `applicationContext.xml` (I omitted unnecessary code) :

```
    ...
    <cache:annotation-driven />

    <bean id="redisCacheMap" class="java.util.HashMap">
        <constructor-arg index="0" type="java.util.Map">
            <map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Integer">
                <entry key="ruleCache" value="86400"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    ...
```

The code above is configured to set the expiration of `ruleCache` to only 1 day (86400 in ms).

Is it possible to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Redis accepts integer value (maximum is up to 2 147 483 647) for expire command. The unit is second, not ms, so 1 year is 31556952 instead of 31556952000, and it fits into integer.

If you want your map to access Long, maybe you can adapt your config:

```
<map key-type="java.lang.String" value-type="java.lang.Long">
```

Comment: Hey great, thanks! I just realized that it's in seconds, not ms.

Comment: The year has 365 days on a normal year (not leap) which makes it `31,536,000` (365 X 24 X 60 X 60). So if you want to average a year actually is 365.25 which gives `31,557,600`. Even using a time library [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/) I got  `31,622,400`. Where/How did you get the `31,556,952`?

Comment: @Azteca - An average Gregorian year has 365.2425, ref: https://www.conversion-metric.org/time/years-to-seconds

Comment: The max is `9223372036854775807` not `2147483647` for `expire`, try it.