# Upper and lower time limits for redis key expiry time

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

Are there limits (upper/lower bounds) on the amount of time that a key in redis is allowed to persist? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 3):

There are 4 Commands to Make a Redis Key Expire :

- [EXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/expire)
- [EXPIREAT](https://redis.io/commands/expireat)
- [PEXPIRE](https://redis.io/commands/pexpire)
- [PEXPIREAT](https://redis.io/commands/pexpireat)

> - **EXPIRE** (Time Passed in Seconds)
>
> Set a timeout on key. After the timeout has expired, the key will
>   automatically be deleted.
>
> Example :
>
> ```
> redis> SET mykey "Hello"
> "OK"
> redis> EXPIRE mykey 10
> (integer) 1
> redis> TTL mykey
> (integer) 10
> redis> SET mykey "Hello World"
> "OK"
> redis> TTL mykey
> (integer) -1
> redis>
> ```
>
> - **EXPIREAT** (Time Passed as Unix Timestamp)
>
> EXPIREAT has the same effect and semantic as EXPIRE, but instead of
>   specifying the number of seconds representing the TTL (time to live),
>   it takes an absolute Unix timestamp (seconds since January 1, 1970). A
>   timestamp in the past will delete the key immediately.
>
> Example :
>
> ```
> redis> SET mykey "Hello"
> "OK"
> redis> EXISTS mykey
> (integer) 1
> redis> EXPIREAT mykey 1293840000
> (integer) 1
> redis> EXISTS mykey
> (integer) 0
> ```
>
> - **PEXPIRE** (Time Passed in MiliSeconds)
>
> This command works exactly like EXPIRE but the time to live of the key is specified in milliseconds instead of seconds.
>
> Example :
>
> ```
> redis> SET mykey "Hello"
> "OK"
> redis> PEXPIRE mykey 1500
> (integer) 1
> redis> TTL mykey
> (integer) 1
> redis> PTTL mykey
> (integer) 1498
> ```
>
> - **PEXPIREAT** (Time Passed in MiliSeconds TimeStamp)
>
> PEXPIREAT has the same effect and semantic as EXPIREAT, but the Unix time at which the key will expire is specified in milliseconds instead of seconds.
>
> ```
> redis> SET mykey "Hello"
> "OK"
> redis> PEXPIREAT mykey 1555555555005
> (integer) 1
> redis> TTL mykey
> (integer) 58130168
> redis> PTTL mykey
> (integer) 58130167824
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Got an issue `ReplyError: ERR value is not an integer or out of range` and have the same question about maximum TTL, so, I found that the maximum value (! in seconds) is 2 147 483 647.
The more detailed answer you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28085785/set-cache-redis-expiration-to-1-year)

Answer (score 1):

The precision of expiration is millisecond (with `SET KEY VALUE PX mill` or `PEXPIRE mill`). So, the min expire time is 1 millisecond.

The max expire time is infinite, i.e. if you do NOT set any expiration, the key will never expire.